# MVC URI routing causes repeated link on the address bar when redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with the URL Router. The router works properly when manually type the URL on the address bar like

```
http://localhost/mysite/home/index
```

I am using this .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which redirects all request to index.php in the root directory.

With the URL:

```
 http://localhost/mysite/home/index
```

it calls the controller which generates the view and inside the view I have the link to home page.

```
<a href='http://localhost/mysite/home/index/' alt='test'>HOME</a>
```

When I click I got something like this on the address bar

```
localhost/home/index/localhost/home/index/localhost/home/index
```

It properly redirects but it causes the repeated URL as shown above, and I don't know how to solve it. The more I click, the more URL is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More important is how you create URL for that anchor. If you click on anchor you get as parameter full path `localhost/mysite/home/index`. Maybe it will be better if you create a virtualhost for your site.

Comment: This helps solve the problem. I specify the path with <base> tag then I can just put something like <a href="home/index"> in the links. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not need your internal application links to contain your domain name (here `http://localhost`). If you omit this, all links/forms within your application will be relative to your domain.

Thus, this URL in a `<a>`:

```
http://localhost/mysite/home/index
```

can be more cleanly expressed as:

```
/mysite/home/index
```

This means your app will work on any domain you connect it to, and on any protocol (`https` as well as `http`).

The only time you need to explicitly reference the domain is:

- When you are redirecting using `header('Location: ')`
- When you are referring to a domain other than your current one
- When you wish to switch protocol